# How can I output a range of split lines Power Automate

Tags: arrays, string, csv, split, power-automate

I followed this link to learn how to split my csv file into multiple lines.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Sliting-multiple-lines/td-p/90297

It only shows how to export 1 line with expression " outputs('Compose_Find_NewLines')[0] "

Is is possible to output a range of lines? I am trying to split the csv file into multiple files of certain ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop + New Step -> Search 'Do Until'

On the loop you can get the first element of the array and pass it to a new Array variable or to your new file and then use the function `skip` to remove the element from the main array. Do it until you reach your number of rows and then move to the next file.

Example of the Flow - let's assume you want to pass N rows:

```
Trigger
Initialize variable (mainArray)
... //get the data from CSV and add to mainArray

initialize variable int (i)
initialize variable array (secondArray)
do Until i == N:
    Compose I: @outputs('Compose_Find_NewLines')[0]
    append To variable secondArray
    Compose II: @skip(variables('mainArray'), 1) //eliminate the first row from mainArray
    set Variable main Array to Compose II
    Compose III: i = i + 1
    set variable i = Compose III
```

Do as many loops as files you want to split i.e. if you have 30 rows and want to split into 3 files of 10 then N = 10 and you do 3 loops.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. That was similar to what I ended up doing. For small files it is perfect. I have to extract 80k lines at a time so the do until method took about 1-1/2 hours to complete. I changed it to do that step by step outside of a do until since I know how many files I need out of it. It now takes 1 - 2 mins.